# Is it possible to navigate ul's that are nested in separate div with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make keyboard navigation between ul's that are nested in separate divs for grid reasons. Is it possible? I've been only successful with ul's within the same div container.

```
<div class="four columns">
<ul class="project">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="four columns">
<ul class="project">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your existing keyboard navigation code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the markup is exactly what you have postet, you can navigate to the **next ul** with:

```
$(this).closest("div").next().find("ul.project")
```

and to the **previous ul** with:

```
$(this).closest("div").prev().find("ul.project")
```

Always assuming that `this` is your current `ul`.

And you maybe want to replace `div` with `div.four` or `div.columns` if you want to check uls in divs with a specific class only.

Answer (score 0):

One option, based on what exactly you are doing can be

```
$(this).closest("div").next().find("ul")
```